# Worksheet is larger than the window

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, window, dimensions

I have a worksheet saved which is larger than the Excel 2007's work area.

This means when I open the worksheet I cannot access the corners of the worksheet to reduce the size and the worksheets title bar area (with move, size, minimise, etc) is hidden beneath the ribbon. Even if I remove the ribbon, I still can't see the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

"Right-click" on Excel's icon on the task bar. This will bring up a menu. Click on "move" and then use your arrow keys to reposition the window.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to get the program's context menu (similar to clicking on the icon in the upper-right of the window.

Then pressing left & right will go through the entire program's menus, but (depending on the program) can also go to the individual worksheet's context menu.  If you get there you can then go down to *"resize"*, which will give you the 4-arrows resize icon for the worksheet itself (not the main program window).  Then press the <kbd>down</kbd> key, and the <kbd>right</kbd> key (which will let you resize the lower-right corner).  Then use the mouse to resize the worksheet.

Then press <kbd>enter</kbd> (or click the left button) to finish resizing.  This helps with windows are larger than the screen and you're unable to resize them.

Finally, go back to the original author, and swap their incredibly huge high-res screen with a more sane one.  You'll never have this problem again :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **View** on the ribbon and select **Arrange All** then OK. Does that restore the window size to something accessible?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> which will maximize the window (even if it's larger than the screen) since Windows Vista

You can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or right click the Excel button on taskbar (the preview button since Windows 7) then select **Maximize**